# Error al instalar weblogic: No se ha podido acceder al registro del sistema ni modificarlo

Tags: java, windows, weblogic

Trato de instalar weblogic pero me sale este error, lo baje desde oracle y es un archivo .jar, ya tambien trate de ejecutarlo con cmd y me sale lo mismo
[image: No se ha podido acceder al registro del sistema ni modificarlo]

como lo puedo instalar correctamente?
o que otro servdor me recomiendan??,
voy a empezar a trabajar con JSF

Comment: Si vas a empezar con JSF, usa Jetty o Tomcat, le agregas la librería de JSF manualmente y tienes más libertad que al usar un servidor de aplicaciones tan pesado que ralentiza el desarrollo. Ahora, considera que JSF **solo es un MVC**, no es un framework que intente integrar acceso a datos y demás capas de tu aplicación con la vista. Para eso puedes usar frameworks como CDI o Spring.

Comment: Ya probaste a correr tu instalador como administrador?

Answer (score 0):

Su error puede que esté relacionado con establecer el `MW_HOME` en las variables de entorno, puede que me equivoque pero he visto problemas por ésta variable, el siguiente [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e18840/install_config_12_1_3.htm#EOHWL223) tiene un paso a paso de Oracle directamente para la instalación de WebLogic Server, puede que le sirva.

En cuando a otros servidores de aplicaciones JavaEE, hay varios:

1. Glassfish
2. Jboss | WildFly (mas reciente)
3. TomEE

A mi parecer, se me ha hecho fácil Glassfish, en comparación con Jboss, no he utilizado TomEE, pero pues sé que es una "versión" de Tomcat que soporta las tecnologías de la especificación de JavaEE como lo son `EJB, JMS, CDI, JTA` cosa que Tomcat no hace, sólo es un contenedor de servlets, por lo que permite utilizar sólo `JSP` y su respectiva librería `JSTL` y pues obviamente Servlets como tal.

Netbeans por ejemplo, viene con Glassfish en su instalación como opción y pues es muy intuitivo para empezar, claro está que cualquier servidor de aplicaciones es bastante fácil de implementar pero ya cuando se trata de configuraciones, me parece que Jboss es un poco mas confuso.

Answer (score 0):

En general recomiendo, si se va a instalar *Weblogic* en *Windows*, se haga en una `carpeta/directorio` fuera de las carpetas de sistema, es decir, fuera de *Program Files* y fuera de *Users*. Eso significa que no es una instalación por defecto.

El error que muestra es precisamente ese, que no tiene permisos para modificar el registro y terminar de instalarse correctamente.

Ejecuta el cmd con permisos de administrador y lanza:

```
java -jar blablabla.jar
```

> Puede ser **wls1036_generic.jar** o **fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar** etc... en función del paquete que hayas descargado desde *Oracle*.

Si lanzas la instalación así, estoy casi seguro que funcionará correctamente.